# Java - How to make Comparable Array of Strings

Tags: java, string, comparable

I feel this is a simple question, but I cannot find the write format online.
How would I go about making a Comparable array of strings?

Like this:

```
Comparable<String> = {"A", "C", "J", "O", "Z"};
```

Or do I start it like:

```
Comparable<String> = new Comparable<String>();
```

Similar to an arraylist, I am not to sure.

I am using the Comparable interface so I can declare two lists, one of strings one of ints, and I may sort them using a specific sorting algorithm, all my current problem is how to initialize the array

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Do you want to compare String elements together?

Comment: How would the comparison work exactly?

Comment: Yes I am trying to compare strings in a sorting algorthm by input[j].compareTo(input[i]) < 0
And none of them compile

Comment: String itself will compare in a specific order, why do you still need to manually write a comparable for them?

Comment: What are you expect the comparison to do? I think there is no default implementation of this because there is no straight forward, always valid definition of the result of an array comparison. If your goal is to order the contents of the list (for example by sorting), than not the list has to be comparable but its elements.

Comment: Lists, or arrays? What types are you working with, _specifically_?

Comment: @Sean Are you trying to compare `list vs list` ? `array vs array` ? or `string vs string` ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create an instance of `Comparable`. Because the String class already implements this interface, you can simply call the method `.compareTo(String otherString)`

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("hello");
myList.add("hello");
System.out.println(myList.get(0).compareTo(myList.get(1))); //prints out 0
```

You can just populate the list like usual

Comment: An actual example of how to sort for the OP ? BTW, why do you use `new` to create your strings ? This prevents the JVM from interning the strings and does not really bring any value

Comment: @Dici Just out of habit; I'm used to using lists for other objects where you have to create new instantiations. Noted

Comment: Okay ! Just to make sure, do you know about interning ?

Comment: @Dici Yes; it's virtually always better to use `'myString"` rather than `new String("myString")`. Again, it was just out of habit

Answer (score 1):

`Comparable<T>` is an `interface`, so you can't directly declare anything to be of that type.  The normal idiom for `Comparable` is that if you're declaring your own class to be comparable, you declare it like this:

```
class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {
    // ... other fields, methods

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyClass other) {
        ... something that returns <0, 0 or >0
    }
}
```

If you look at the language's definition of `String` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), you'll see that `String` already implements `Comparable<String>`.  So a `String` is already comparable and already has a `compareTo` method.  You don't need to do anything else to make it comparable.

To set up an array, the syntax is

```
String[] myArray = {"A", "C", "J", "O", "Z"};
```

To set up an `ArrayList` (which can grow or shrink),

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "C", "J", "O", "Z"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP's intent is not clear, but if the purpose of the question is how to create an array that is `Comparable` - since it's an interface that array does not implement, and since array cannot be overridden - it's simply not possible.

However, one can use a `Comparator` for a specific type for the purpose of comparing two instances of that type.

Most of the classes in Google Guava's [com.google.common.primitives](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/package-summary.html) package have a static `lexicographicalComparator()` method returning a `Comparator` for arrays of the primitive type the class handles.

Guava currently does not have a similar solution for Object arrays, but if you can use an `Iterable` instead the static [Comparators.lexicographical(Comparator)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#lexicographical-java.util.Comparator-) or the [Ordering.lexicographical()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#lexicographical--) on an existing `Ordering` might help.

Following what I understood as the OP's intent, let's assume we have two arrays:

```
String[] arr1 = {"A", "C", "J", "O", "Z"};
String[] arr2 = {"A", "C", "J", "O", "X"}; // different last element
```

We can now compare these two arrays using `Ordering.lexicographical()`:

```
        int comparison = Ordering.natural()
                .lexicographical().compare(Arrays.asList(arr1), Arrays.asList(arr2));
```

The result will be positive, since arr1 is considered greater than arr2, because the first element in arr1 that was not equal to its corresponding element in arr2 was greater according to `Ordering.natural()`.